# Get the cart total in ng repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am working on ng repeat and wanna get the grand total of the all sub total in cart .

Here is the fiddle link .

I have idea to iterate the json by this

```
$scope.total = function() {
        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {

        })

        return total;
    }
```

but its getting complicated   in my case

http://jsfiddle.net/75m7e/744/

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution that keeps your current structure mostly intact:

change the view from `{{total}}` to  `{{total()}}` and implement your function like so:

```
$scope.total = function() {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
       total += item.price * item.qty;
    })

    return total;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t4bbj8h2/

Keep in mind that this is far from an ideal solution, but without more info what you are trying to do here we can't give you much help improving your application.

Answer (score 0):

You could add handy [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library and do

```
$scope.total = function() {
    var total = 0;
    _.map($scope.items, function(item) { 
        total += parseFloat(item.price || 0) * parseFloat(item.qty || 0); 
    });
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :

http://jsfiddle.net/75m7e/745/

```
$scope.total = function() {
        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
            if(item.isProduct=="1") {
            total += item.price * item.qty;
            } else if ( item.isProduct=="0" ){
            total += (item.weight/1000) * item.price ;
            }

        })

        return total;
    }
```

Comment: Do not forget to replace `{ total }}` to `{{ total() }}`.